# Convert regex to rust regext. Replace text between nth comma

Tags: regex, rust, replace

The goal is to use a regex to remove text between the nth and the next comma in rust.

For example outside of rust I would use

`^((?:.*?,){4})[^,]*,(.*)$`

on `London, City of Westminster, Greater London, England, SW1A 2DX, United Kingdom`

to get a desired result like:

`London, City of Westminster, Greater London, England, United Kingdom`

I don't have a strong understanding of regex in general unfortunately. So I would learn more about the mechanic and be able to use it in the program I'm writing to learn rust.
Just copy pasting it ala

```
let string = "London, City of Westminster, Greater London, England, United Kingdom"
let re = Regex::new(r"^((?:.*?,){4})[^,]*,(.*)$").unwrap();
re.replace(string, "");
```

is not working obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you want to remove is the fifth comm-delimited value, not the fourth, and you need to replace with two backreferences, `$1` and `$2` that refer to Group 1 and Group 2 values.

Note it makes it more precise to use a `[^,]` negated character class rather than a `.*?` lazy dot in the quantified part since you are running it against a comma-delimited string.

See the Rust demo:

```rust
let string = "London, City of Westminster, Greater London, England, SW1A 2DX, United Kingdom";
let re = Regex::new(r"^((?:[^,]*,){4})[^,]*,(.*)").unwrap();
println!("{}", re.replace(string, "$1$2"));
// => London, City of Westminster, Greater London, England, United Kingdom
```

Comment: I see, from my tests I had the fourth `{3}` inside the rust example at first which was a mismatch with the regex above, I corrected it shortly after posting.
Your answer works and clarifies. I bow down to you my friend, thanks a lot

Comment: Nit: `$1` and `$2` refer to capturing groups. Backreferences are things inside the pattern itself and are not supported by Rust's regex crate.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 `$1` and `$2` here are [*replacement backreferences*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html), and "things inside the pattern" are [*inline backreferences*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), but this terminology is not canon.

Comment: I'm the author of the regex crate. I specifically did not use the backreferenxe terminology like this because it is super confusing. See also: https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Captures.html#method.expand